# Asignar texto (String) a un RadioButton dentro de un RadioGroup

Tags: android, radiobutton, radiogroup

Soy nuevo en android y quiero que me ayuden a asignar el texto a los `radiobutton` que están contenidos en un `RadioGroup`, gracias.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton1;
    RadioButton radioButton2;
    RadioButton radioButton3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);

        //Asignar Texto de cada RadioButton ?
        radioButton1.setText( "ONE");
        radioButton2.setText("TWO");
        radioButton3.setText("THREE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás asignando al `radioButton1` el `R.id.radio1` tres veces.

```
 radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
 radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
 radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
```

Cámbialo por:

```
 radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
 radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
 radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
```